# Calculating empirical probabilities

Tags: r, probability

It feels like this should have been asked, but having searched stats.stackexchange I cannot find answer.

I have this vector of numbers in R:

```
x <- c(0.01, 0.50, 0.00, 0.28, 0.00, 0.15, 0.67, 0.00, 0.23, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.23, 0.00, 0.15, 0.00)
```

Using R code, how do I calculate the probability of a range of values? For example, what is probability of a value being between 0 and 0.01?

In addition, using R code what is probability of a value being 0.3 or less?

Comment: Do you want to empirically answer the proportion of values between some values, or do you want to fit some kind of probability density estimate?

Comment: This is what I was after: 'empirically answer the proportion of values between some values'. But would still be nice if you could show how to 'fit some kind of probability density estimate'

Comment: This is purely personal interest. In fact I feel guilty, because I've been fiddling with probability distributions all day when I should be trying to finalise my thesis

Answer (score 4):

When you say "between" you should say which endpoints (if any) are included

There are many ways to tackle these; I'm not doing these in efficient ways, just illustrating a variety of approaches.

One method for P(a < X <= b) type problems:

```
diff(ecdf(x)(c(0,0.01)))
```

and for P(X <= b):

```
ecdf(x)(0.3)
```

Another approach, for getting P(X=x):

```
table(x)/length(x)
```

and for getting P(X <= x):

```
cumsum(table(x))/length(x)
```

So if you want to include both endpoints, you could do this:

For P(a <= X <= b):

```
p <- table(x)/length(x)
diff(ecdf(x)(c(0,0.01)))+ p[names(p)=="0"]
```

or:

```
p <- table(x)/length(x)
sum(p[names(p) %in% c("0","0.01")])
```

or just

```
length(x[0<=x & x<=0.01])/length(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you know anything else about what those numbers represent?  For example, I note that none of the numbers are negative.  Also the number 0 occurs a lot (11 times) so  given that none of the numbers are negative, you're not dealing with a normal distribution.  With only 19 numbers in the sample, there are going to be big error bars on any calculations that you do with those numbers, unless you know that e.g. the numbers all come from a particular distribution.  Otherwise, the answer to a question like "what is probability of a value being 0.3 or less" just comes from counting.  With 19 numbers in the sample, and only two numbers greater than 0.3, the probability of a value being 0.3 or less is 17/19.

Answer (score 0):

I just created a quick function that tells you the proportion of values in a numeric vector that are greater than or equal to `start` and less than or equal to `end`:

```
emp_prob<-function(x,start,end){
sum(end>=x & x>=start)/length(x)}

x <- c(0.01, 0.50, 0.00, 0.28, 0.00, 0.15, 0.67, 0.00, 0.23, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.23, 0.00, 0.15, 0.00)

emp_prob(x,0,1)
[1] 1
```

This is a pretty basic question, so a tutorial in R would probably help.